# Writing null-terminated string "R5" in hexadecimal, etc

Tags: string

This is supposed to be a low-level course, and it is only the third day of class. However, we are asked to "Write the null-terminated string 'R5' in hexadecimal, binary, and octal notations. Assume that ASCII code is used"

I have no idea where to go to learn how to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What's the ASCII for 'R'?  Does that help to get you started?  Did you answer in hex, binary, octal, or decimal?

Comment: Looking at this ASCII chart, I find that the hex for 'R' is '0x52'.

I also see that the hex for '5' is '0x35'. Does that mean that the hex for R5 is '0x520x35'? I honestly am just completely lost here. Is there a tutorial I could read up??

Comment: shouldn't you be learning this from your textbook?

Comment: I can not afford the textbook. Thus, my coming here.

Comment: 0x is a prefix used in many programming languages, including C, to indicate that the following number is hexadecimal. So sometimes you'll see 52 in hexadecimal written as 0x52.

Answer (score 1):

NULL-terminated ASCII strings are stored with one byte per character, plus one byte for the NULL. You would therefore be printing three bytes - 'R', '5', and 0.

Look up 'R' and '5' on an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see what the numeric values are for those characters in ASCII. Then, write out your three bytes three different ways - one each for hexadecimal, binary and octal.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help, craig65535. I find that the three bytes, respectively, are '52', '35', and '30'. I now have my three bytes, but I am unsure what to do with these from here...

Comment: the third byte is 0, not 30. 0x52, 0x35, 0x30 would be literally the characters `R50`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this just requires you to look up the appropriate entries from the ASCII table, which in most cases lists hex and octal and the characters themselves.

ASCII is a standard way of defining how characters are represented, and most tables will list characters against corresponding hex, decimal, and octal values. The first 128 is standard and the next 128 are the extended characters (those weird characters that don't map to an English keyboard).

If you google "ASCII table" you'll be inundated with different links. The top one I saw at www.asciitable.com appears to have everything you need - except binary.

Most of the times you're not going to see binary listed, but it's fairly academic to translate a hex value into binary - your Windows Calculator will happily do this for you.

To more directly translate your specific string you'll look up each character (including the NULL) separately and translate each individually.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately to the computer, everything is a number. To represent characters such as letters or symbols, we can agree on an *encoding*, or a numbering of these characters. For example, we could invent a new encoding where 1 means 'A', 2, means 'B', and so on. ASCII is one commonly used text encoding which maps characters to numbers.  In this case, we are concerned with a string of 3 characters: `'R'`, `'5'`, and `null` (a null character marks the end of a string. It is represented by the value 0. If you look in an [ASCII table](https://www.google.com/search?q=ASCII), you'll find that the numeric values are `82`, `53`, and `0`.

```
String: R, 5, <null>
Decimal numbers: 82, 53, 0
```

Our normal number system is base-10, or decimal. This means that each digit represents a value ten times larger than the next (1, to 10, to 100, to 1000, etc.). Alternate bases include 8 (octal), 16 (hexadecimal), and 2 (binary). There is a straightforward way to convert between bases, although you can also easily find calculators that will do the conversion for you. You may want to review the relevant section of your textbook, or check out the Wikipedia articles. For the example of decimal 82, the hexadecimal value is 52 (this means 5*16 + 2 = 8*10 + 2). Oftentimes you will see a prefix of "0x", this is commonly used to make it clear the following digits are in base 16. (otherwise, you might think "52" refers to the decimal value 52).

---

> Interesting. So would it be correct to say that the null-terminated string "R5" is simply "52, 35, 30" or is there a more correct format to it? Thank you for your patience. –

As I pointed out in another comment, the actual *value* 0 marks the end of a string, not the value 0x30, which represents a character '0' in the string. Note that the value of zero (`0`) is the same regardless of which base your numbers are in.

```
String: R, 5, <null>
Decimal : 82, 53, 0
Hexadecimal: 52, 35, 0
```

Comment: Interesting. So would it be correct to say that the null-terminated string "R5" is simply "52, 35, 30" or is there a more correct format to it? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I see now. I mistakenly looked up the hexadecimal equivalent of the character 0 instead of using the value 0. My question though was just inquiring to whether there was a proper format (such as writing the three all together ala 52350). I see now they're simply meant to be listed sequentially.  Thanks for your patience. 

If I'm not mistaken, R5 then would be written in octal as "122, 065, 0".

Thanks for your time, I'll read up on this. Cheers.

Comment: yes, you've got the general idea. There's no one right way to write out numeric representations of strings, although something like `52350` is definitely *wrong*, because people would most likely read the digits as `5, 23, 50`. use spaces or commas for best clarity. A fixed two-digits-per-character listing like `0x523500` may also be acceptable in some situations.